# Lots of free memory, but Java won't start (SunOS 5.10)

Tags: solaris, memory, java

*vmstat* gives:

```
swap        free
37489684    110178592
```

Still I have issues, while trying to run *Java* process with 10g heap:

```
> java -Xmx10g -Xms10g -d64 HelloWorldApp

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

Why it happens and how to remediate the issue?

**Update.** Output of *ulimit -a*:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 10
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 25525
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Comment: Is your machine 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: 64-bit powerful server machine

Comment: Can you post result of `ulimit -a`?

Comment: @Gnouc Done * * *

Comment: You may think you have the memory available but if is not *contiguous* then the HotSpot JVM cannot use it. However I'm more inclined to think that there's a hint in why you can allocate up to exactly 4GB. That sounds like a 32Bit limitation but you say you're using the `-d64` switch so that can't be case. What version of Java ?  (output from `java --version`, please).

Comment: @nolan6000 32/64 is definetelly not the case. I can start another node without any issues, but not this one. Memory thrashing may be the case. Is there any memory defrag mechanism is embedded in modern server OSs?

Comment: Yeah, I believe the JVM would complain if you added the `-d64` command line option without actually having installed the JVM 64-bit overlay. Memory defrag tool? Hmm. That would be a system restart.  :-). Again I find it suspicious that you seem to be able to allocate up to exactly 4GB. Can't be a coincidence.

Comment: Still would want to see output from `java -version -d64`, please.

Comment: @nolan6000
    java version "1.7.0_25"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

You can have available RAM but still run out of swap. I believe this could be what you are experiencing. Investigate with `swap -s`.

As a second idea the problem may be due to the fact that there isn't enough *contiguous* memory available although it would seem fairly odd if the OS cannot find 10 GB contiguous free memory when there seems to >100 GB free.

Comment: It's definetelly could be the case, because Java allows to start process with heap no larger than awailable swap space. After start, swap space is reduced to that exact amount (heap size). It's only a question why system uses swap instead of RAM?!

Comment: If you cannot grow swap on disk could you swap over a ramdisk?

Comment: It doesn't use Swap space instead of RAM, but Solaris doesn't overcommit memory so you need to have enough swap to account for the memory reservations you expect. The JVM is in fact doing a memory reservation when it is trying to grab that 10 GB. Increase your swap and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your swap area is highly undersized. A large part of the RAM reported to be free is in fact currently unusable because it serves as a backing store to other programs memory reservations. Just add some swap, it can be a simple file, and you'll be able to launch your JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following instead:

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -d64 HelloWorldApp
```

or

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -d64 HelloWorldApp
```

May also be because it is too high.

Comment: Works with up to 4g.

Comment: You absolutely need +4g?

Comment: Yes I do. But it's not about my needs, it's about why am I not available to use RAM which should, by my logic, available?

Comment: Ok. What is your output of free -m? Also from when you are running the java program with 4g.

Comment: free tool is, unfortunatelly, unavailable on Solaris.

Comment: Do it with vmstat then... before and after you have started java with 4g